# Função "onClick" e "onLongClick" são chamadas com um único toque

Tags: java, android, onclick

estou com um problema simples, porém que não encontro uma solução específica para esse problema.
Dentro do meu aplicativo tenho uma Recycler View e nela tenho dois eventos de click: um para toque simples e outro para toque longo.
Quando eu executo o toque longo ele é executado, porém quando eu tiro o dedo da tela o toque simples é acionado também(o que não deveria acontecer).
Preciso que o toque simples não seja chamado após o toque longo ser executado.

Esses são os eventos de click implementados na minha activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(Tarefa tarefa) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditarTarefaActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void onLongClick(Tarefa tarefa) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "on long click funcionando!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

No meu adapter ele está sendo chamado dentro do método onBindViewholder:

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Tarefa tarefa = tarefas.get(position);
        holder.bind(tarefa);

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick.onClick(tarefa);
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            onClick.onLongClick(tarefa);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do [`setOnLongClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener), você precisa retornar `true` se realizar uma ação, `false` se não realizar.

Passando `false`, é interpretado que a função não foi executada, então o `setOnClickListener` é executado, causando o problema que você descreveu.

```java
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        onClick.onLongClick(tarefa);
        return true; // Aqui
    }
});
```